# How to plot interlocking tori?

Tags: r, plot, gnuplot

How can I plot interlocking tori in R as shown on [this page for gnuplot](http://milonga.physics.metu.edu.tr/twiki/bin/view/TWiki/GnuPlotPlugin):

[image: interlocking tori]

I tried following codes in R but they do not work:

```
try_tori_1 = function(){
    library(rgl)
    xvec= yvec = seq(-pi,pi,by=0.1); 
    z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) {sin(x)+.5*sin(x)*cos(y)} )
    persp3d(z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue")
    z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) {cos(x)+.5*cos(x)*cos(y)} )
    persp3d(z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue", add=T)
    z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) {.5*sin(y)} )
    persp3d(z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue", add=T)
    z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) {1+cos(x)+.5*cos(x)*cos(y)} )
    persp3d(z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue", add=T)
    z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) {.5*sin(y)} )
    persp3d(z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue", add=T)
    z <- outer(xvec,yvec,function(x,y) {sin(x)+.5*sin(x)*cos(y)} )
    persp3d(z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5, col = "lightblue", add=T)
}

try_tori_2 = function(){
    library(rgl)
    u= v = seq(-pi,pi,by=0.1); 
    plot3d(cos(u)+.5*cos(u)*cos(v),sin(u)+.5*sin(u)*cos(v),.5*sin(v))
    plot3d(1+cos(u)+.5*cos(u)*cos(v),.5*sin(v),sin(u)+.5*sin(u)*cos(v))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is based on the examples from these two websites:

- [3D plots in R](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/02/3d-plots-in-r.html)
- [R: Fun with surf3D function](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-fun-with-surf3d-function/)

And here's how you do it:

```
library(plot3D)
x <- seq(-pi,pi,by=0.1)
y <- seq(-pi,pi,by=0.1)
R = 1.0
r = 0.5
M <- mesh(x, y)
alpha <- M$x
beta <- M$y
surf3D(x = (R + r*cos(alpha)) * cos(beta), 
       y = (R + r*cos(alpha)) * sin(beta), 
       z = r * sin(alpha), 
       col="blue", colkey=FALSE, alpha = 0.3, border="black", 
       xlim=c(-0.5*pi,0.5*pi), ylim=c(-0.5*pi,0.5*pi), zlim=c(-0.5*pi,0.5*pi))
surf3D(x = R + cos(alpha) + r*cos(alpha) * cos(beta), 
       y = r*sin(beta), 
       z = sin(alpha)+ r * sin(alpha) * cos(beta), 
       col="red", colkey=FALSE, alpha = 0.3, border="black", add=T)
```

Which generates this plot:

[image: interlocking tori]

The important things to note are:

- use the `surf3D` function
- set up your angles using `mesh`
- to see it all, specify ranges (`xlim`, etc) with the first plot
- plot with the colors and alphas to get the coloring you are after

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that with `misc3d` (which renders an interactive `rgl` plot).

```
library(misc3d)
R <- 3; r <- 1
fx <- function(u,v) (R+r*cos(u))*cos(v)
fy <- function(u,v) (R+r*cos(u))*sin(v)
fz <- function(u,v) r*sin(u)
parametric3d(fx, fy, fz, umin=0, umax=2*pi, vmin=0, vmax=2*pi, color="red")
gx <- function(u,v) fx(u,v) - R
gy <- fz
gz <- fy
parametric3d(gx, gy, gz, umin=0, umax=2*pi, vmin=0, vmax=2*pi, color="blue", 
             add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: An elegant solution!