# R data sets for 3D geometric shapes such as a torus or sphere?

Tags: r, topology

I'm unable to find any R data sets simply representing shapes in 3-space. For instance, I would like a sample data sets of points for a torus in 3-space so that I can use persp for showing a surface plot and then use a Sammon mapping to 2-space and show another plot and investigate the structure preserving properties of Sammon mappings.

Comment: perhaps cran r geozoo to build your torus

Comment: You could also generate your own. Useful reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852177/how-to-plot-3d-parametric-equations-in-r/23852389#23852389 could help